# Facebook Wall module

Tags: social-network

I'm trying to use the [Facebook wall](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_wall) module for the first time. I've installed it, created a Facebook App and thought that I'd entered all the right configuration information on both. However, the Facebook Wall/Settings/Page Information is telling me that it's "Not able to connect with Facebook".

Quite happy to accept that I've done something wrong but not a clue where to turn to diagnose what's happening as there doesn't appear to be any more information. Can anyone give me any pointers please?

If there's a good resource to guide me that would be really helpful - for example there seem to be different types of Access token, which one should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the permission to write to a user's wall, either during signup or doing it manually later - looks like you are missing that permission. You need to get appropriate permission from the facebook.

Comment: OK, thankyou for the suggestion. I'll have a look at that although in fact this module isn't about writing to a user's facebook wall, I just want to show their last few facebook posts on their website.  The client is a small charity who would like to keep updating their facebook status but also show the posts on their website. Perhaps I'm going about this in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

That module shows that error if it cannot connect to https://graph.facebook.com using CURL, so I suspect either CURL isn't installed on your server or you've entered the Page Name/Access Toekn incorrectly

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I may have the tokens wrong and I'll have another go. I'm a Newbie and not familiar with what CURL is, I'll need to read up on it.  I'm using GoDaddy as a host, would I need to install something or is it somethign that GoDaddy would provide?

Comment: According to https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5614/which-components-does-my-hosting-support GoDaddy has CURL support

Comment: Thanks, you beat me to finding it :-)  So I guess I must have the tokens wrong, OK, I'll try again! Thanks for your help.